# Xcode 6.1.1 shortcut cmd+click on a function name doesn't work anymore

Tags: xcode

Xcode 6.1.1 shortcut cmd+click on a function name doesn't work anymore:

in prev version of xcode you could see the code of a function, or a variable just by click on name with cmd key down..

Now it doesn't work or I have to activate it somehow??

Fix: after clean installation, it's works again!

Comment: nope it definitely still works, I tried looking in preferences to see if I could find maybe you toggled it off-- but I couldn't find anything

Comment: I've a lot of problems opening my xcode 6.1 project with xcode 6.1.1

now I try to do i clean installation and reopen my project again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It definitelly works.**

But you could try keyboard-only solution:
**Preferences > Key bindings > Find > Jump to definition** and also you can set it up there.

Comment: but I can't put click on it!

Comment: First try it witk keys only and if it works, make sure your cmd key works or try the right one

Comment: now I have done a clena installation of xcode and it works again: thank you!